# Spring: set TransactionPhase on event publisher instead of listener

Tags: java, spring, event-handling

In Spring you can publish event by ApplicationEventPublisher and set TransactionPhase on event listener, e.g. :

```
@TransactionalEventListener(phase = TransactionPhase.AFTER_COMMIT)
```

Is there a way to set TransactionPhase while publishing an event, not while handling? Something like:

```
applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(new SomeEvent(), TransactionPhase.AFTER_COMMIT);
```

Can I set TransactionPhase on publisher? Or is there another publisher that I can use and it works this way?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: We have custom implementation of event bus (we persist event do DB and after commit it's sent to Kafka) and we want to have analogical behavior in integration tests without using Kafka

Comment: Little curious, how it would help you in integration tests?